# Extract common parts of Jenkins JobDSL job definitions into reusable functions

Tags: groovy, dsl

I have many Jenkins jobs looking approximately like the example below. I wanted to create reusable functions to encapsulate repetitive parts of [the Jenkins Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/), so that I can then apply these across the job definitions.

Here are two implemented solution attempts and one additional idea (without implementation).

I'd like to ask about this proposed approach, or for alternative suggestions I can try to implement next.

```
package jobs

pipelineJob("Build Proton") {
    description "Job to build Proton"

    parameters {
        stringParam('PROTON_EXTRA_CMAKE_OPTIONS', '', '')
    }

    definition {
        cps {
            script(readFileFromWorkspace("pipelines/buildProtonPipeline.groovy"))
            sandbox()
        }
    }
}
```

### Option #1: Pass what's needed in parameters

```
// in DslCommon.groovy
class DslCommon {
    def static applyDescription(WorkflowJob pipelineJob, String jobDescription) {
        pipelineJob.with {
            description(jobDescription)
        }
    }

    def static applyDefinition(def dslFactory, WorkflowJob pipelineJob, String pipelinePath) {
        pipelineJob.with {
            definition(applyDefinition(dslFactory, pipelinePath))
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method for setup definition of the pipeline
     * @param dslFactory (this)
     * @param pipelinePath path to pipeline script
     * @return closure with configuration
     */
    def static applyDefinition(def dslFactory, String pipelinePath) {
        return {
            cps {
                script(dslFactory.readFileFromWorkspace(pipelinePath))
                sandbox()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this as

```
package jobs

import io.strimzi.ci.DslCommons

pipelineJob("Build Proton") {
    DslCommons.applyDescription(delegate, "Job to build Proton")

    parameters {
        stringParam('PROTON_EXTRA_CMAKE_OPTIONS', '', '')
    }

    definition(DslCommons.applyDefinition(this, "pipelines/buildProtonPipeline.groovy"))
}
```

### Option #2: Misuse of closures to reduce parameter count

```
private static defineScript(String s, Closure c) {
    DslFactory this_ = c.thisObject as DslFactory
    WorkflowJob delegate_ = c.owner.delegate as WorkflowJob

    delegate_.definition {
        cps {
            script(this_.readFileFromWorkspace(s))
            sandbox()
        }
    }
}
```

This can be then used as

```
package jobs

import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.WorkflowJob

pipelineJob("Build Proton") {

    // ...

    defineScript("pipelines/buildProtonPipeline.groovy") {}
}
```

### Option #3: Define extension methods for JobDSL?

I did not try to implement this (yet), but according to blog article [Groovy DSL Builders #7: The Extension](https://musketyr.medium.com/groovy-dsl-builders-7-the-extension-d612fd261471) and Groovy doc page [Pimp my Library Pattern](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/spec/doc/design-pattern-pimp-my-library.adoc) ([example code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/spec/test/DesignPatternsTest.groovy#L1000-L1023)), I should be able to extend the JobDSL with the methods I need.